# how to calculate number of bounded faces in a graph?

Tags: data-structures

Let G be a simple undirected planar graph on 10 vertices with 15 edges.If G is a connected graph,then the number of bounded faces in any embedding of G on the plane is equal to?

How to solve these types of questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be computed according to Euler's formula and you can find the proof here [Euler characteristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Planar_graphs)

Comment: by euler's formula-V-E+F-C=1,then no. of faces i.e f=7 then why the answer is 6?

Comment: Did you consider the outer space as a face?

Comment: No i have not considered outer space,i have just applied the formula,do we have to include outer space as well,is that explicitly mentioned in question?

Comment: Yes the outer space is considered as a face in Euler's formula